# close vote dialogue freaks out when pasting too long url

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Well, the title says it all:

[image: screenshot of a random close vote dialogue, shifted to the right inside its borders]

This happens when I paste a long url in the duplicate question input so that it exceeds the length of the input. Which in case overflows to the left, outside of the dialogue box, shifting the whole content. The blue "focus" rectangle seems to stay of the correct width, though.

I've experienced this in Opera 12 on Windows, but then confirmed it on Chrome (39.0.2171.99 m) which is the screenshot actually.

Comment: This is [how it looks like in Firefox 35](http://i.imgur.com/n3bcqSE.png) on Windows. P.S. here is that [long link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088365/why-wouldnt-i-use-child-prototype-parent-prototype-rather-than-child-prototyp).

Comment: Happens on meta too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. It will be live after our next production build.